# How to intercept chunk migration in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I want to intercept chunk migration events of a particular (sharded) collection.
The changeLogs collection (from the Config server database) is not capped and we can't define a tailable cursor over it. One solution could be to copy the events of interest from the changelog collection into a capped one and query it with a tailable cursor. I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do as far as "intercepting events"? What version of MongoDB server are you running? Are you sure your `config.changelog` is not capped? The `config.changelog` collection should be capped at 10MB by default unless you have changed this for your deployment.

Comment: I want to be notified whenever a chunk is moved succefully from one shard to another and to get the _IDs of the moved documents. 
I use hash bases sharding for some of my collections.

Is Config.chunks also capped?
If config.ChangeLog is capped, can i define a tailable cursor over it?


I'm using MongoDB 3.4 and my aim is to develop an administration console for my cluster.

Thank you for your help :)